# Kafka consumer seek operation is not returning data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a requirement where I have to monitor a consumer group externally and also check the consumer record for a particular offset which is already consumed by that above consumer group. I created an `AdminClient` to connect to the cluster and do that operation.

Now, when I am trying to do `assign()` and `seek()` operation to the particular offset and then poll the data, it always returns an empty map.

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
```

Below is my code. I logged in to control center and I can see data for the below topic-partition and offset. Please help me in identifying the issue.

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "server_list");
properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
properties.put("ssl.truststore.location", ".jks file path");
properties.put("ssl.truststore.password", "****");
properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "****");
properties.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "****");
properties.put("group.id", grp_id);
properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
// properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,grp_id);  
//properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");  
properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");

KafkaConsumer < String, String > consumer = new KafkaConsumer < String, String > (properties);

try {

    TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition("topic1", 1);

    consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0));
    long offset = 19 L;
    consumer.seek(tp, offset);
    boolean messageend = true;

    try {
        while (messageend) {
            ConsumerRecords < String, String > records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
            if (null != records && !records.isEmpty()) {
                for (ConsumerRecord < String, String > record: records) {
                    if (record.offset() == offset) {
                        System.out.println("Match found");
                        messageend = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                messageend = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: From which offset is it polling?

Comment: it is supposed to poll from the given above offset (offset = 19L)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean by "externally monitor", but you should not use the same consumer group name to read from the topic if there are already active consumers in that group.

In other words, your consumer will join the group and could cause a rebalance for existing consumers, or it'll join as idle and consume nothing if the assigned partition is already assigned elsewhere in the group. This seems to be the case you're running into.

You should be able to do this more easily on the CLI

```
kcat -C -b kafka:9092 -t topic1 -p 1 -o 19 -m 1
```

Comment: I cannot use cli , I have to get it programmatically

Comment: Okay, that was only an example. Did you read the rest of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. How many partitions do you have for topic1? There need to be at least 2 for you to seek the TopicPartition("topic1", 1).
2. the timeout 10 ms is rather short for me when consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
3. Do you have any other consumer in the same group? if number of consumer in the same group is bigger than number of partition, then there will be idle consumer, so it has no assignment, so seek and poll will fail